# Проблема с почтой Debian 8

Tags: debian, postfix, onlyoffice

Я установил onlyoffice и обнаружил проблему, что не отправляются письма. Вот последние строчки **mail.log**

```
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20680]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20680]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases: lookup of 'root' failed
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20681]: 5F5FB1740020: to=<root@web4u.in.ua>, relay=local, delay=186302, delays=186302/0.25/0/0.12, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (alias database unavailable)
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20680]: D377F1740017: to=<root@web4u.in.ua>, relay=local, delay=14399, delays=14399/0.21/0/0.13, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (alias database unavailable)
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20681]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20681]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases: lookup of 'root' failed
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20680]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20680]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases: lookup of 'root' failed
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20680]: AFB651740018: to=<root@web4u.in.ua>, relay=local, delay=362413, delays=362412/0.31/0/0.11, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (alias database unavailable)
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20681]: 3B8391740D11: to=<root@web4u.in.ua>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=103614, delays=103614/0.39/0/0.11, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (alias database unavailable)
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20680]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20680]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases: lookup of 'root' failed
Mar 17 11:12:17 web4u postfix/local[20680]: A3584174004A: to=<root@web4u.in.ua>, relay=local, delay=102602, delays=102602/0.46/0/0.07, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (alias database unavailable)
Mar 17 11:12:21 web4u postfix/smtp[20684]: 529A917400FE: to=<diefair@mail.ru>, relay=mxs.mail.ru[217.69.139.150]:25, delay=548, delays=542/0.04/0.17/4.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1agTye-0004oF-Hg)
Mar 17 11:12:22 web4u postfix/qmgr[30488]: 529A917400FE: removed
Mar 17 11:14:42 web4u postfix/pickup[22034]: 584401740047: uid=1000 from=<admin>
Mar 17 11:14:42 web4u postfix/cleanup[22037]: 584401740047: message-id=<20160317091442.584401740047@mail.web4u.in.ua>
Mar 17 11:14:42 web4u postfix/qmgr[30488]: 584401740047: from=<admin@web4u.in.ua>, size=779, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 11:14:45 web4u postfix/smtp[22086]: 584401740047: to=<diefair@mail.ru>, relay=mxs.mail.ru[217.69.139.150]:25, delay=3, delays=0.33/0.01/0.18/2.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1agU0y-0004vF-K7)
Mar 17 11:14:45 web4u postfix/qmgr[30488]: 584401740047: removed
Mar 17 11:36:41 web4u postfix/smtpd[26214]: error: open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
Mar 17 11:36:41 web4u postfix/smtpd[26214]: connect from cityd.cityhost.com.ua[77.120.99.7]
Mar 17 11:36:41 web4u postfix/smtpd[26214]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from cityd.cityhost.com.ua[77.120.99.7]: 454 4.7.1 <support@webforyou.com.ua>: Relay access denied; from=<support@citydomain.com.ua> to=<support@webforyou.com.ua> proto=ESMTP helo=<cityd.cityhost.com.ua>
Mar 17 11:36:42 web4u postfix/smtpd[26214]: disconnect from cityd.cityhost.com.ua[77.120.99.7]
Mar 17 11:40:02 web4u postfix/anvil[26216]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:77.120.99.7) at Mar 17 11:36:41
Mar 17 11:40:02 web4u postfix/anvil[26216]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:77.120.99.7) at Mar 17 11:36:41
Mar 17 11:40:02 web4u postfix/anvil[26216]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Mar 17 11:36:41
```

я не очень в этом разбираюсь, буду благодарен за любую информацию

Comment: Здравствуйте, Пожалуйста, уточните, что именно было установлено у ONLYOFFICE, а также способ установки и версию продуктов?

Comment: устанавливал как обычный  deb пакет. устанавливал сам офис, без документ сервера. последнюю версию. проблема в том, что не приходят письма с активацией

Comment: @DmitrySpilberg поскольку вы не можете пока что публиковать комментарии, вот вам [чат для комментариев](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37119/discussion-on-question-by-diefair----debian-8).

Answer (score 1):

набрать от пользователя root или через sudo  команду newaliases, тогда появится файл aliases.db

Comment: -bash: newaliases: command not found

Comment: sudo newaliases. Если не работает, то переставить postfix заново.

Answer (score 0):

в логе присутствует одна и та же ошибка от программы *postfix*:

> alias database unavailable

и подробнее:

> error: open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory

в документации к postfix [рекомендуется](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps) выполнить (от имени root-а):

```
# postalias /etc/aliases
```

или

```
# newaliases
```

оба этих файла (`postalias` и `newaliases`) должны идти в комплекте с программой *postfix*. если она установлена из одноимённого пакета из официального репозитория дистрибутива, то месторасположение файлов таково:

```
$ apt-file list postfix | grep 'postalias\|newaliases' | grep bin
postfix: /usr/bin/newaliases
postfix: /usr/sbin/postalias
```